# T-SQL equivalent to MySQL aggragate from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm struggling to do something in SQL Server that is super easy in MySQL.

I want to grab some columns (let's just say one for simplicity) from one table and then a count other columns of another table based on a key from the first table and have both values in my result set.

The following query works in MySQL but does not in SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    ph.PONum, 
    COUNT(pd.POLine) AS LineCount
FROM 
    POHeader AS ph
INNER JOIN 
    PODetail AS pd ON ph.POnum = pd.PONum
WHERE 
    ph.PONum = 4444
```

Results:

[image]

What is the SQL Server (T-SQL) way to do this?

Comment: MySQL doesn't use the `[table_name]` notation.

Comment: Yes I know but, that's not the point of this question.

Comment: Ah, I read it as you were trying to use that on the MySQL side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike MySQL, SQL Server does not assume what columns you want to group by. Every column that is not being aggregated needs to be defined in the `GROUP BY` list.

For your query it should be:

```
SELECT 
    ph.PONum, 
    COUNT(pd.POLine) AS LineCount
FROM 
    [Dbo].POHeader AS ph
INNER JOIN 
    [Dbo].PODetail AS pd ON ph.POnum = pd.PONum
WHERE 
    ph.PONum = 4444
GROUP BY 
    ph.PONum
```

Comment: So if I have 20 fields I'm grabbing I have to do GROUP BY field1, field2, field3, etc? wow is that inconvenient

Comment: Unfortunately yes.

Comment: @S.Mason that's the SQL standard. MySQL deviates on some points from the SQL standard.. unless you are using `SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',only_full_group_by');` then MySQL is following the SQL standard with the GROUP BY  see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ece0d7/5

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a *correlated* subquery.  EG

```
SELECT 
    ph.PONum, 
    ( select COUNT(*) from PODetail where PONum = ph.POnum ) LineCount
FROM 
    POHeader ph
WHERE
    ph.PONum = 4444
```

Comment: You mean a corelated subquery

Comment: You are technically correct - the best kind of correct.